# How to add attributes in a XSD using Excel VBA for automation

Tags: excel, xsd, vba

In a particular XSD, I need to add a lot of attributes. So I would like to automate the process using Excel VBA.

I am very new to VBA , started to study the basics.

I came across this site which had told how to add attributes in XML by VBA.

http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-update-xml-file/#comment-74761

I refered thier code and wrote a code for XSD.

```
Sub UpdateXML()

Call fnUpdateXMLByTags

End Sub


Function fnUpdateXMLByTags()

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook

Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFileName = "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Python\VBA\XSDs\job.xsd"
oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)

Set ApplicantNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/PurchaseOrder/text()")

 'Add new Attribute to the Node

 Set ParentNode = oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("/Application/USAddress/xs:attribute")

' add its attribute
 Set newChildAttribute = oXMLFile.CreateAttribute("name")
 newChildAttribute.Text = "Country1"
 ParentNode.Attributes.SetNamedItem (newChildAttribute)

 Set newChildAttribute = oXMLFile.CreateAttribute("type")
 newChildAttribute.Text = "xsd:NMTOKEN"
 ParentNode.Attributes.SetNamedItem (newChildAttribute)

 Set newChildAttribute = oXMLFile.CreateAttribute("fixed")
 newChildAttribute.Text = "US"
 ParentNode.Attributes.SetNamedItem (newChildAttribute)


oXMLFile.Save (XMLFileName)

End Function
```

I am trying this on a sample XSD and here for now trying to add the attribute

below

The XSD on which I am working on is the following one( I refered from a book)

http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema”>

```
<xsd:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">  

    <xsd:sequence>  
        <xsd:element name="ShipTo" type="tns:USAddress" maxOccurs="2"/>  
        <xsd:element name="BillTo" type="tns:USAddress"/>  
    </xsd:sequence>  
    <xsd:attribute name="OrderDate" type="xsd:date"/>  
</xsd:complexType>  

<xsd:complexType name="USAddress">  
    <xsd:sequence>  
        <xsd:element name="name"   type="xsd:string"/>  
        <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>  
        <xsd:element name="city"   type="xsd:string"/>  
        <xsd:element name="state"  type="xsd:string"/>  
        <xsd:element name="zip"    type="xsd:integer"/>  
   </xsd:sequence>  
   <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:NMTOKEN" fixed="US"/>
```

The basic thing I need is how to add a attribute to a XSD containing elements and other attributes using Excel VBA.

Please help me. I am stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

Atrributes can be added to an element within and XML file using setAttribute

```
.setAttribute("country", "UK");
```

[Live Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_createattribute3)

However in your question I think you maybe confusing terminology, are you asking how to modify the XML Schema (XSD) or modify the XML document.

> The basic thing I need is how to add a attribute to a XSD containing
>   elements and other attributes using Excel VBA.

Comment: I need to add the attributes in XSD only and not in XML. I could find code to add attributes in XML, but not in XSD. That is the problem.